# Pyramid: How to get all app's routes within a view?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid

I want to see all the routes which my application has. Return them as a response like key=>value pair:

```
'route1' => '{foo:\w+}'
'route2' => '{baz:\w+\d+}'
... and so on
```

But I don't know how to get them within my view. For example, this is my view. I want it to return a map of routes. I do this:

```
@view_config(route_name='route1')
def someView(request):
    routes = request.registry.settings.getRoutes()  ## what should I print here to get a map of routes?
    r = ''
    for k,v in sorted(routes.items()):
        r += str(k) + "=>" + str(v) + "<br/>";
    return Response(r)
```

There is a `RoutesConfiguratorMixin` class with `get_routes_mapper` method. I tried to import the class and called its method but got an error that no `registry` was in the instance of it:

```
from pyramid.config.routes import RoutesConfiguratorMixin as Router

r = Router();
routes = r.get_routes_mapper();
## ... and the same code as above
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 ways, one is supported (public) and one is unsupported (private).

Option #1 is to use the introspector and is explained [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/introspector.html).

Option #2 is to use the route mapper (which is not a public api), in the way that the pyramid debugtoolbar does in its [routes panel](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_debugtoolbar/blob/master/src/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/routes.py).

Comment: Documentation for Option #1 can now be found here: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.6-branch/narr/introspector.html

Comment: which documentation is the right one depends on the version of pyramid you are using, can be switched in the page (currently in the lower right corner) the link to the latest version is currently here: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/introspector.html

Answer (score 5):

Pyramid installs a bin script called `proutes` for that purpose.

Comment: this is not an answer but an adequate comment, please consider using the comment section next time

Answer (score 1):

Install pshell then
pshell  to login to pshell with your app config.
then run

```
print("\n".join([r.path for r in app.routes_mapper.routelist]))
```